# Character count for SublimeText/WordCount

Tags: characters, sublime-text-3, plaintext

I'm new to Sublime Text (using ST3) and I've managed to install the SublimeText/WordCount package via Package Control.

https://github.com/SublimeText/WordCount/blob/st3/readme.md lists `enable_count_chars` as a preference that I can set to 'true'.

But I have no clue how to do that. Yes yes, I've tried googling it, but I'm having no luck finding it and I'm sure someone knows exactly how to do it :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Select *Preferences → Package Settings → Word Count*
2. Select either *Settings - Default* or *Settings - User*
3. In the word-count–settings file that is opened, enter your Word Count settings
4. Save

On a Mac, you'll need to copy and paste the settings from *Settings - Default* to *Settings - User* and edit from there.

[image: Screenshot of Word Count settings in SublimeText]

Comment: `[On a Mac,] you'll need to copy and paste the settings from Settings - Default to Settings - User and edit from there.` …or just pick *Settings - User* in the first place.

Comment: Hi Synetech. Actually, on a fresh install of ST3 and WordCount package on a Mac, the *Settings - User* page was blank, and *Settings - Default* was locked/uneditable. So, there is a need to copy the latter settings page to make up your own one. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm, when I do this (on a Mac) it works for approximately one second after saving the `Settings - User` file, then reverts to the default behaviour. Any idea why? (I'll post a separate question if not.)

Comment: Why on Earth is my button for Package settings missing, below is the image of the preference menu items I can see... 

<IMG>https://i.pinimg.com/564x/60/8e/67/608e67e8b703995cf76c15c15423c2ea.jpg </IMG>

god I miss ST2

Answer (score 36):

You just need to select the text that you want to count its words, characters or lines and then read the information shown on the status bar at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Note that in Sublime Text 3 this only works when the find/replace UI is closed (very annoying!).

Answer (score 7):

Select all characters with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Look at bottom left corner

left corner screenshot:

[image]